# SCons: How to copy build information across computers?

Tags: scons

I do not have all the required programs to compile my project in the same computer. I can compile one part in one computer and the rest in a different computer. I want to run

- `scons path/to/first/file` in one computer.
- `scons path/to/second/file` in a different computer.

The second file depends on the first file. I compiled the first file in one computer and copied it over. However, when I try running scons on the other computer, I get an error because `scons` wants to re-build the first file. The message I get if I add `--debug=explain` is `Cannot explain why '/full/path/to/first/file' is being rebuild: No previous build information found`. I have also tried copying the `.sconsign.dblite` file over between machines and that hasn't worked. Help?

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to resolve this is likely to only specify building the part each computer can build based on the presence of the build tools which can build it.

So detect if the computer has `compiler_a` and then do something like:

```
if compiler_a:
   # do all compiler_a build stuff
else:
   # do all compiler_b build stuff
```